# Does Linux kernel since version 5.0 have a CR0 protection?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

In kernel versions 2.X through 4.X, you could have easily overwritten the 16th [CR0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#CR0) bit in kernel modules with:

```
write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~ 0x10000));
```

This way it used to remove the write protection on the syscall table. Now, on versions 5.X, however, this doesn't seem to overwrite the CR0 bit. If you try hijacking the syscall table after using the forementioned trick,

```
sys_call_table = (void *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000));
iamhere("Saving the old call..");
old_open = sys_call_table[__NR_open];
iamhere("Setting the new one..");
sys_call_table[__NR_open] = hijacked_open;
write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000);
```

you are greeted with a 0x0003 permissions violation error.

[image: The error]

 So, my question is: have new kernel mode protections been put in place? If so, are there still any possible ways to bypass that for the case of rootkits in example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [sensitive bits in CR0 and CR4 are pinned since version 5.3](https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2019/11/14/security-things-in-linux-v5-3/), at least *via* `write_cr0` and `write_cr4`. Your code fails because the `write_cr0` call doesn’t clear the WP bit.

If you’re in supervisor mode, you can always write CR0 directly, which should avoid the pinning; but the pinned bits will be restored the next time `write_cr?` is called. (The point of the pinning is to prevent attacks involving calls to these functions.)